# Conflict between recyclerview scroll and viewpager swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

In my app I have a ViewPager that has four fragments. All the fragments are composed  of  RecyclerView which can be scrolled vertically. My problem is that when I try to navigate to other fragments and swipe left or right, the RecyclerView's scroll is detected first (mostly) and instead of going to other fragments the RecyclerView gets scrolled.

To be more clear, if I scroll the recyclerView, then suddenly swipe left or right, the viewpager never swipes.

What should I do?

Comment: This should work fine as in google play store. If your app misbehaves unlike play store app, then it should be taken care by looking on to your code. Check it and let us know.

Comment: Do you mean that it will work fine when uploaded to playstore?

Comment: No. Never. I took Google play store as an example to compare. Can you update with the layout structure you use?

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll your `RecyclerView` vertically and cross a threshold to trigger scrolling, it consumes the `TouchEvent`. This means the default behavior is until you release your finger from the screen, the `ViewPager` will not be able to trigger a horizontal scroll. This is default behavior for how scrolling views interact with each other. You could attempt to override touch handling by extending `RecyclerView` and `ViewPager` or having a coordinating view that dispatches all `TouchEvent`s to both views. However, either of these approaches could present a number of issues.

If you were to look at the Play Store for reference, its touch handling works the same as what you are seeing here.

Comment: Even after a single vertical scroll on recyclerview(still scrolling), when I release my finger and try to swipe left or right, the recyclerview still intercepts the touch.

Comment: You'll have to add some sample code of anything you've customized on touch then. I've done many implementations of `ViewPager`s (horizontal) containing a collection `RecyclerView` (vertical) with no problems.